# How to recover a file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, file, recover

I accidentally deleted a `.java` in Eclipse, then renamed its package. Is there any way to recover it?

If I undo, it tells me that I cannot undo the renaming of a package.

Comment: Pro tip: Use source control.

Comment: Check your local history.

Comment: Check your Recycle Bin or whatever.

Comment: Short of using some file recovery tool, no, you can't get the file back.  As suggested above, ALWAYS use a source control system even if only working on personal projects.  I use git.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-87b.htm ?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sometimes it's the source control itself that deletes the file-with-uncommited-changes (misuse by the user or even a buggy implementation of the source control software). An option to send files to the system Recycle Bin or Trash is always good (many programs that delete files offer this option)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you try right click on the project > Restore from Local History...?

Comment: You are nothing short of a super hero!

Answer (score 1):

According to the versioning software you are using (ex. svn, cvs), just revert or update it to  the latest version.